# How to move Azure Elastic Pool between different SQL Servers

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-elasticpool

I'm looking to move Azure Elastic Pool from one Azure SQL Server to another Azure SQL Server.

I'm not sure if its possible to do so, as I tried to look around internet for the same but couldn't find any information.

Please suggest any approach to do so if its feasible (within the same subscription or into different subscription as well).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I tool that is worthy to try on this scenario is [Azure Resource Mover](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/resource-mover/overview). It supports Azure SQL Elastic Pools as you can read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/resource-mover/overview#what-resources-can-i-move-across-regions).

If the tool does not help, then create the new Azure SQL logical Server, on the newly created server now create a new Azure SQL Elastic Pool, the move the database from one elastic pool to the other using CLI.

```
# Get the database ID
dbId=$(az sql db show --resource-group myResourceGroup --server myserver1 --name mydb --query id --output tsv)

# Move the database to the new elastic pool
az sql db update --ids $dbId --elastic-pool mypool --server myserver2
```

Please read [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/scripts/move-database-between-elastic-pools-cli?view=azuresql) for more detailed steps.

Comment: thanks for your response but, I'm looking to move "Elastic Pool" created in one SQL Server to another SQL Server, and both the SQL Servers are in the same subscription. "Azure Resource Mover" is not helping me out as its asking to move dependent services which I cannot move as they both reside in same server.

Comment: Then the only other option I know is moving the databases one by one. I shared with you an example using CLI,